# Pseudo element color change on parent elements's active state change

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a menu with a dropdown, its icon gets represented by a pseudo element. I need the color of the latter to be green when the dropdown is not active, but when it is active the pseudo element should feature the same color as its parent.

Not active: [image]

Active: [image]

Simply adding the condition that when not active the color become green solves the problem, but the code does not work for me

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('li#menu-item-57');
if (elem === !document.activeElement) {
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.et-menu .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child:after { color: #ACD375;}', 0);;
}
```

```css
.et-menu .menu-item-has-children>a:first-child:after {
  font-family: ETmodules;
  content: "3";
  font-size: 35px !important;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 8px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu-item-57" class="et_pb_menu_page_id-55 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-55 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-57"><a href="" aria-current="page">Get Involved</a></li>
```

But I did not succeed, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS code as well.

Comment: Need more info like how background is set to your icon in CSS. And try also SVG with `fill: currentColor` https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/

Comment: The OP's code never reaches beyond `if (elem === !document.activeElement)` due to the **negation of** `document.activeElement` ... `!document.activeElement` equals `false` and `elem` strictly compared to `false` as well will be always `false`. The comparison should be `(elem !== document.activeElement)` and the rule will be inserted as intended.

Comment: btw ... a styling system which forces 10 class-names into a single element's class-list and moreover introduces names like `'et_pb_menu_page_id-55'`, `'menu-item-type-post_type'` or `'menu-item-object-page'` is very questionable.

Comment: another hint ... [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) belongs to the [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) which are used with a double colon `::` ... [CSS pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) as mentioned with the OP's title do target specific states of an element and get used with a single colon `:`.

Comment: @Giovanny ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Comment: @Giovanny … Regarding the provided answer / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my above comments ...

> *"The OP's code never reaches beyond `if (elem === !document.activeElement)` due to the **negation of** `document.activeElement` ... `!document.activeElement` equals `false` and `elem` strictly compared to `false` as well will be always `false`. The comparison should be `(elem !== document.activeElement)` and the rule will be inserted as intended."*

> *"another hint ... [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) belongs to the [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) which are used with a double colon `::` ... [CSS pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) as mentioned with the OP's title do target specific states of an element and get used with a single colon `:`."*

> *"btw ... a styling system which forces 10 class-names into a single element's class-list and moreover introduces names like `'et_pb_menu_page_id-55'`, `'menu-item-type-post_type'` or `'menu-item-object-page'` is very questionable."*

```js
const elm = document.querySelector('li#menu-item-57');

if (elm !== document.activeElement) {
  document
    .styleSheets[0]
    .insertRule('.et-menu .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child::after { color: #ACD375; }', 0);
}
```

```css
.et-menu,
.et-menu .menu-item-has-children {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.et-menu .menu-item-has-children > a:first-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  /* right: -10px; */
  /* top: 8px; */
  content: "3";
  font-family: ETmodules;
  font-size: 35px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  /*color: #ACD375;*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="et-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="" aria-current="page">Get Involved</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But, though the OP's above changed code does display the pseudo-element, the scripting approach chosen by the OP will never be aware of any further occurring state changes of the menu.

A css only approach on the other hand does.

One just needs to choose appropriate pseudo-classes like [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) and choose/target the correct elements for additional css rules.

```css
.et-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.et-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 8px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.et-menu a:link
.et-menu a:hover,
.et-menu a:focus,
.et-menu a:active,
.et-menu a:visited {
  color: #999;
}

.et-menu li:not(:empty) {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.et-menu li > a:first-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: -12px;
  content: "⌄";
  font-family: ETmodules;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #acd375;
}

.et-menu li:focus-within,
.et-menu li:has(a:active) {
  background-color: #acd375;
}
.et-menu li > a:first-child:focus,
.et-menu li > a:first-child:active,
.et-menu li > a:first-child:focus::after,
.et-menu li > a:first-child:active::after {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<ul class="et-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" aria-current="page">Get Involved</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```